# How to add endstop to a sonoff drived stepper motor?

Tags: wiring, home-automation

I would like to control a motor for my curtains from Google Home. I will use a sonoff switch.
How could I wire an endstop between the sonoff and the motor to stop the motor ?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. This is more of an electronics question, and probably off-topic here. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: Sonoff refuses to get an actual UL listing or equivalent.  As such, their products are illegal for use in the US or Canada in any connection with 120V mains power.  It's fine if all the wiring connected to the Sonoff is low voltage.

Comment: @harper thanks for the warning. All wiring will be low voltage.

Comment: You could use a proximity sensor , we use them all the time for control in motor circuits , check out automation direct on line for good prices the product sensors are made in ac or dc versions in low voltage. Something like an at1-so-4h  10-30v dc inductive prox when it sees metal it turns on. There are smaller ones and other easy ways to do this this just happens to be a limit switch I use . Automationdirect.com  , I have no connection to this company other than purchasing parts from them , they ship quickly and rarely have backorders. Also simple spring loaded leaf switches could be used.

Comment: We need to know more about the system to provide a useful answer, what type of motor control and the voltage? If just switches we have to get creative but even then it can be done. P.S. I agree with Harper on the listing for their switches.

Comment: Thanks to all. Sorry, I misunderstood the purpose of this forum. Indeed my question is an electronic one and I will search help on an electronic forum.